# In Xamarin, how to active PanGesture in ScrollView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Background: Recently, I was developing a search bar which is a Entry. I find it is much reasonable to unfocus the Entry when I slip somewhere else. So I use PanGestureRecognizer to get the slip movement. But when encounter an ScrollView or any other View inherited from ItemsView, the PanGestureRecognizer didn't work. It seems that the ScrollView override the pan gesture to implement scroll movement.

So, is there any method to active PanGestureRecognizer when I scroll or slip in ScrollView?

Comment: Could use "scrolled" instead of PanGestureRecognizer then?

Comment: No. Scrolled is not sufficient since small pan movement counld not trigger scroll event either.

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there any method to active PanGestureRecognizer when I scroll or slip in ScrollView?

This is a known issue. See: [[Android] PanGestureRecognizer doesn't work with ScrollView/ListView and TapGesture](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1977)

The person who opened the above issue discusses some possible workarounds: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1977#issuecomment-467688741